# How to assign file names with space to another variable without losing the separator

Tags: bash, shell, quoting

I have a bash script like:

```
files="${@:2}"
for f in $files; do
  echo $f
done
```

which takes the shell expansion from the second argument to the last, and print it. However it does not work with files with spaces. It prints files:

```
test image.jpg
```

as

```
test
image.jpg
```

If I use:

```
for f in "${@:2}"; do
  echo $f
done
```

without assigning it to $files, it works fine.

I also tried to use the first case with quoted `"$files"`, and does not work. It prints all files in one line. How can I assign the file names to another variable, while still making it work when using expansion like for in loop?

Comment: tried using "${files}"?

Comment: @Ketan it prints all file names in one line

Comment: in that case you need to add a new line in echo. Try using printf in place of echo: printf "$f\n"

Comment: @Ketan Try it please. It does not work as you think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make that work, you need `files` to be an array, not a variable.  Try:

```
files=("${@:2}")
for f in "${files[@]}"; do
  echo "$f"
done
```

Example:

```
$ bash script.sh first "test image.jpg" "another test.txt"
test image.jpg
another test.txt
```

#### Discussion

From the original code, consider this statement:

```
files="${@:2}"
```

This assigns all arguments after the first to `files` as a single undifferentiated string.  We can see that with this script:

```
$ cat test.sh
files="${@:2}"
declare -p files
$ bash test.sh first "test image.jpg" "another test.txt"
declare -- files="test image.jpg another test.txt"
```

As you can see, all distinction between the second and third arguments has been lost.

Comment: This works! The key is to use `()` around the elements in assignment and use `$var[@]` in the for-in loop... Thanks! Will accept this when allowed.

Comment: Glad it worked.  To be precise, it needs to be `"${var[@]}"`.  Both the double-quotes and the braces are important.